# Posting random value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

```
var myArray = ['horizontal', 'vertical', 'fade'];
```

I'm trying to make it MODE random.. Couldn't make it

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bx').b({
  mode: 'fade'
  auto: true,
   });
  });
```

Comment: We don't know about your `b` plugin.

Comment: @Lekhnath Fortunately we don't need to know either.

Comment: @Juhana Unfortunately there may be the implementation for generating random values but not working due to some reason.

Comment: @Lekhnath That's very unlikely.

Comment: @Juhana but has probability.

Comment: @Lekhnath Based on the OP's comment, the probability is 0.

Comment: @Styli Why don't you update your question instead of adding the comment.It makes your problem understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Math.random() to generate an index to use for myArray, e.g.

```
var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length);

...
mode: myArray[id],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a function to return a random element from an array:

```
function rand(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
}
```

Putting it together...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bx').b({
    mode: rand(myArray)
    auto: true,
  });
});
```